# Convert Struct to JSON

Tags: c#, json, struct

I have a struct, I want to convert it to JSON and save it as local file.

I couldn't find any source that explain how to convert a C# struct into a JSON.

I am using a console application for that, not a webservice/web, etc.

Comment: Take a look at http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: [JSon.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) is pretty easy to use, with plenty of tutorials.  There are also built in serializers with AJAX and WCF, but I find them not very straight forward to use, and occasionally buggy..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[JavaScriptSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
YourStruct myStruct = new YourStruct(x,y,z);
var json = serializer.Serialize(myStruct);
```

[JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

The other alternative JSON.net, does not depend on System.Web.* assemblies:

```
YourStruct myStruct = new YourStruct(x,y,z);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myStruct);
```

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer is in in an ASP.NET assembly.

Comment: @SeanU, that's true. He didn't asked for a specific approach. But I'll put a example with JSON.net

Comment: Nothing would stop you from referencing *System.Web.Extensions.dll* in a console app..

Comment: You also can't name a variable `struct` unless you use `@struct` :)

Comment: @MikeChristensen As long as it's installed. But ASP.NET components aren't included in the client profile, so I figured it was worth mentioning.

Comment: Is this method still an efficient way to do it?

Comment: @DonCarleone yes, nothing changed. On .NETCore there's the new Json library from Microsoft, but the workings are the same.

Comment: Thanks @MarceloDeZen !

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using [JSon.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx).  You can then do something like:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj); // myObj is the struct you want to serialize
File.WriteAllText("Foo.json", json); //Write the text to Foo.json
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Install https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/
2. Use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(structName)` to serialize object. Do not forget to change argument name to yours